# Trouble installing Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 on HP Z200

Tags: server, 18.04, system-installation, crash

Obligatory I'm new here sentence.

Anyways, I've recently picked up an old HP Z200 Workstation, with an i3 540 in it and 8GB of ram.

Anyways, I've tried to install Ubuntu Server to it. I can get to the menu screen. But as soon as I hit the Install option, the system just freezes and restarts. I've tried using different programs to flash the USB, and also tried a different USB drive. The first drive I tried, just kept reporting a Casper unitrd read error. The second drive doesnt throw any errors, but it just freezes. Before I got to that point, it would show the purple screen, before restarting.

I'm not really sure why its doing this. I've successfully installed ubuntu server to a laptop before, and had it run various game servers, but that was a weaker system. This is the reason to why I want to install it to this system instead.

[Edit, a little progress I guess?]
Managed to install ubuntu from another machine. When that drive is installed in the other machine, it shows the grub bootloader screen, and as soon as it goes to start ubuntu, it just restarts.

Comment: Did you verify the download was flawless (ie. checksum), and then verify the thumb-drive it was written to before attempting install (there are many ISO's you could have downloaded, most offer this option, some with it very visible, others it requires a key to have that menu appear).  Did you use the 'live' installer? or which installer?

Comment: I have not. I'm honestly not sure how to go about doing this. And I've used the ububtu-18.04.2-server-amd64 iso. Does it need to be the live version?

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck   (thumb-drive or any install media is referred to as CD; and screens will differ. I don't recall what you see on that ISO but if you see kbd?-in-rectangle & person-in-circle you quickly hit key to see the menu.  Server has multiple install ISOs, with additional features/functions in certain areas (but not others)

Comment: I'll look at the integrity then. I also decided to try the live iso, to see if anything would go differently. Unfortunately, nothing much changed. It still restarts after hitting pretty much any option except boot from hard disk, which obviously fails. And yeah, it had the keyboard and person icon. I've also done things like updating the bios, just in case. I'm starting to wonder if it's something with this particular system. I'm in the process of getting a bootable Windows install going, just to see if that works.

Comment: I usually try a desktop release first on hardware, as it usually has greater capacity to deal with different hardware by default (*servers usually being more vanilla*); and to get a feel of what I should expect after install (also a look at what modules were needed for hardware, as the server installs have less).  *I'm assuming you've already done hardware evaluation, eg. cap. check, thorough (days of) memory testing, stress-tests if you felt necessary*

Comment: Oddly enough, same thing happens with the desktop version of ubuntu. Cant even get into the try without installing bit. I've got an idea though, I might install in legacy mode on another machine, and just put that drive into the system. I wonder if it would actually boot then.